# clone a collection to client and be reactive locally

Tags: mongodb, meteor

A Meteor app makes the same list of products available to all uses. Each user can search and select what he wants. Searching by live filter uses CSS to add style for visual "fast find" functionality.
The client side uses a static template with dynamic data to display the list which is multi level deep. Thus reactive data source is needed to change the displayed list by code. Once the client finished selecting, the code need only to send a code for each of the product selected.

How can I "clone" the products collection from the server to the client. Specifically, How can I have a local 'copy' of the products collection.

Is it:
//client.lib.js
`ProductCol = new Mongo.Collection('productCol')` or
`ProductCol = new Mongo.Collection('null')`.

The collection will need to be modified locally only.

And just loop over the server collection and insert into the client one? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a local collection with:

```
ProductCol = new Mongo.Collection(null);
```

or just more simply:

```
ProductCol = new Mongo.Collection();
```

Don't use a string ``` 'null``!, use the constant ```null`

[An example you might find useful](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/using-meteor-local-collections-to-support-browser-based-cryptography/)